# И: какая часть речи и синтаксическая роль?

Tags: синтаксис, союзы, части-речи

Есть предложение:

> С другой стороны, появилась **и** смертельная опасность разоблачения...

**И** здесь можно заменить на **в том числе** с сохранением смысла.

Помогите разобраться, какой частью речи является и какую синтаксическую роль играет *и* в приведённом отрывке.

Answer (score 2):

Здесь "**и**" - сочинительный **союз** с соединительными свойствами. По семантическим свойствам в этом предложении он близок к двойному союзу "**не только... но и**" (имеет место или появилось **не только** ранее сказанное, **но и**), который классифицируется так же (см. "таблицу 2" частотности союзов, разбитых на группы):

http://rusgram.ru/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7#22

**P.S.** Старайтесь не употреблять выражение "**в том числе**" в предложениях, где невозможно сослаться  на его антецедент (число "чего"). Это явление, к сожалению, распространилось - по вине плохих тележурналистов и их разговорчивых гостей (с их "*мужчинами и в том числе женщинами*"). Простейшее правило:

https://www.efremova.info/word/v_tom_chisle.html#.XQJIQb5lM-U

> Употребляется при присоединении члена предложения, который является
>   **частью** того **целого**, **о котором идет речь в первой части предложения**;
>   включая кого-л., что-л., в том числе и.